# In python3, how to derive a class from subprocess.CalledProcessError

Tags: python, class, exception, subprocess, derived

In a package, I try to replace subprocess.CalledProcessError with a derived exception of mine, easier for an end-programmer.

```
import subprocess

class MyExc(subprocess.CalledProcessError):
    pass
    # def __init__(self, .???)


def run(cmd):
   try:
        res = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
   except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        raise MyExc(exc)
```

End-program :

```
import my_package

try:
    my_package.run("my_exe")
except my_package.MyExc as e:
    print(e.stderr)
```

Result :

```
raise MyExc(exc)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cmd'
```

Should I use :

```
raise MyExc from exc
```

or write init() ? How ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.9.5. What is your exact Python version?

Answer (score 0):

The following works :

```
class MyExc(subprocess.CalledProcessError):
    def __init__(self, exc):
        self.output = exc.output
        self.stderr = exc.stderr

...
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    raise MyExc(exc)
```

Comment: This does not satisfy [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). I suggest you not to change the signature of the `__init__` method. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example where `e.stderr` is not `None`, and in accordance with LSP as [Simone wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68804041/703421). Here the class `MyExc` just transfers stderr into stdout. The other thing is that it can also be treated as a `RuntimeError`.

```
# ---------------- package --------------------

import sys, subprocess

class MyExc(subprocess.CalledProcessError, RuntimeError):
    @classmethod
    def create_from_called_process_error(cls, exc):
        print("switches stdout and stderr")
        return cls(exc.returncode, exc.cmd, exc.stderr, exc.output)


def execute(cmd):
    try:
        res = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True, encoding='utf-8')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        raise MyExc.create_from_called_process_error(exc)

# ---------------- end-program --------------------

# these 3 interceptions give the same result
try:
    execute(["ls", "toto"])     # file "toto" does not exist
except MyExc as e:
#except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
#except RuntimeError as e:
    print("Error : %s" % e)
    print("output: %s" % e.stdout)
```

Another solution is to call the parent's constructor :

```
class MyExc(subprocess.CalledProcessError, RuntimeError):
    def __init__(self, exc):
        print("switches stdout and stderr")
        subprocess.CalledProcessError.__init__(self, exc.returncode, exc.cmd, exc.outerr, exc.stderr)

def execute(cmd):
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True, encoding='utf-8')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        raise MyExc(exc)
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Overriding class method changing their signature is not recommended according to [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Instead of using my `reraise` function, you could define a class method for `MyExc` which will return the `MyExc` instance created from an instance of `CalledProcessError`:

```
class MyExc(subprocess.CalledProcessError):
    @classmethod
    def create_from_called_process_error(cls, exc):
        return cls(exc.returncode, exc.cmd, exc.output, exc.stderr)
```

Then you can raise `MyExc`:

```
def run(cmd):
   try:
        res = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
   except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        raise MyExc.create_from_called_process_error(exc)
```

Note that this won't keep the exception traceback, if you want to preserve it you can adapt the `reraise` function I wrote before:

```
def reraise(exc):
    """
    Changes the exception type from subprocess.CalledProcessError to MyExc.
    """
    _, _, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    raise MyExc.create_from_called_process_error(exc).with_traceback(exc_traceback)
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

If you just want to change the Exception type, you could use this function:

```
import subprocess

class MyExc(subprocess.CalledProcessError):
    pass


def reraise(exc_type):
    """
    Changes the exception type, preserving traceback.
    """
    _, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    raise exc_type(*exc_value.args).with_traceback(exc_traceback)


def run(cmd):
   try:
        res = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
   except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        reraise(MyExc)
```

In your end-program:

```
import my_package

try:
    my_package.run("my_exe")
except my_package.MyExc as e:
    print(e.stderr)
```

*NOTE*: I haven't tested this using `subprocess.CalledProcessError`, but it works with many other exceptions.

Comment: It does not work with subprocess.CalledProcessError, because e.stderr and e.stdout, though well defined, are None.

Comment: I just tested and I get None even raising `subprocess.CalledProcessError`, the behavior seems the same to me. Could you provide an example in which `e.stderr` is not None?